# Webpack. Image loading failed

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-file-loader

Using webpack for the first time. Can't load images in there. Tried a LOT of things to fix it, but...
I included my images in html through **img src**.
I also did import in index.js:

```
    import backGround from '../img/bg.jpg';
    const bgImg = document.getElementById('bg');
    bgImg.src = backGround;
```

So I got this kind of error:
*ERROR in ./src/img/bg.jpg 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type*

I can also show you my config:

```
    {
    test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
    use: [
      'file-loader'
    ],
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yow broh, you need to use url-loader
File loader is for html files and stuff

```js
 // "url" loader works like "file" loader except that it embeds assets
            // smaller than specified limit in bytes as data URLs to avoid requests.
            // A missing `test` is equivalent to a match.
            {
              test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
              loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
              options: {
                limit: imageInlineSizeLimit,
                name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
              },
            },
…..
// More loaders
…..

            {
              loader: require.resolve("file-loader"),

              exclude: [/\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
              options: {
                name: "static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]",
              },
            },
```

Make sure to put file loader at the end

Comment: I got ReferenceError: imageInlineSizeLimit is not defined

Comment: That’s for you to set it, it is a variable

Comment: You can delete it and put 1000 instead

Comment: WOW, no error...but I expected those images to appear in dist folder... is it possible?

Comment: Oh, sorry still not working... I just forgot to uncomment the problematic code

Comment: Then change where it says name

Comment: Change to what?